# In Scala what's the difference between IndexedSeq And LinerSeq

Tags: scala

I am reading about scala datatypes and one thing baffles me. List is a LinearSeq and Vector is a Indexseq.

I read that,  IndexedSeq is good for random access. However, LinearSeq is good only getting first and last element.

however, I am able to access element by index in both the data types, so what's the exact difference?

```
val a = List("a", "b", "c")
val v = Vector("a", "b", "c")

println(a(2))
println(v(2))
```

Comment: The difference is efficiency. `a.last` iterates through every element before the result is returned. Indexing a large `Vector` is much more efficient.

Comment: For `LinearSeq` tail will be **O(1)**, whereas it is takes **O(N)**. On the other hand, `IndexedSeq` makes `apply` _(access by index)_ **O(1)**, whereas it normally is **O(N)**. Anyways, most of the collection traits are useless for users and exists for implementation details, focus on the concrete collection you will use, usually you would choose one according your algorithm.